# Possible to import member into a nested name

Tags: typescript

I have been using rxjs with Typescript using an import like:

```
import * as rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

var stream: rx.Subject<boolean> = new rx.Subject<boolean>();
```

This all works but now I would like to do tree-shaking and it looks likes the way to do this is through "patching" imports [1].  So based upon this I could import the code like this:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
var stream: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
```

This is great, but I would like to keep the symbol names inside of rxjs nested inside a common prefix.  (ex: rx.Subject).  From what I see of how the ES6 import statement works there is no obvious way to do this [2].  What I would like is something like:

```
import {Subject} as rx from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

or any other similar syntax that could allow for this.

Does anyone know a syntax that I could use or a common pattern that people use for this?

1: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/installation.html
2: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a module that re-exports only the symbols that you need from rx. Suppose you name it `rx-subset.ts`:

```
export {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

// an so on
```

Then you can use it everywhere in your source code instead of `rx` like this:

```
import * as rx from './rx-subset'

// here you can use rx.Subject
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do two things I guess. You could do the following:

```
import { Subject as rx.Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
let subject = new rx.Subject();
```

or

```
import * as rx from "rxjs/Subject";
let subject = new rx.Subject();
```

Both of these options should work.